# The best way to work with larger data queries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

After one month of learning and toying around with python and doing tons and tons of exercieses and samples I am still not really able to answer one important question to myself. If I generate data, for example with loading them from a xml or from scraping. How do I work with them? Right now I put each and every entrie directly into a sqlite db.

For exmaple:
I read a news feed, I put id, title, description, link, tags into one row in my sqlite db. I do some categorizing according to keywords within the the title or description. Each news entry goes into one row. After that I can read them row by row or at once.

I can filter them, sort them... But somehow I feel like there is a better way. Put them all with a dictionary into one big list and somehow work with this list. And then after I worked thru them sorted them or got even more infos with that data. Put them into the sqlite db. But none of my books or tutorial talk about this topic!? I try to make an example is a news article more important if a certain keyword comes up multiple times or in with an other keyword. Compare the news from that page with the news from another page with same keywords.

I guess u will be laughing and say. He is talking about ..... how can he not know that. But I am new to all of that. Sooorrry.

Thank you for your help guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have a specific question that's answerable in fewer than 500 words?

Comment: Check out [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html). But a relational database works best with [relational data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model).